# Simple Bar Chart in C#

Tags: c#, graph, charts, mschart

I wanted to ask if its possible to create two simple bars using MScharts to look like this:

[Screen shot http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/4413/desktoptf.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/4413/desktoptf.png)

I want an exact replica of the above image, so no diagram or grids, just two simple bars like these.

Another thing is that the max values are indicated by the small red stripes at each end of the bars and should stay there until the max value is surpassed.

The idea is that I'm reading live data (4 values) that are supposed to dynamically apply to the bars.

So does anybody know how to go about this? I am currently using the MScharts plugin (or would it maybe be better to use the paint function of C# instead of MScharts?).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Ok, heres what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool k = false;
        Random random = new Random();
        int max = 0;

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs paintEvnt)
        {
            int i = 30;
            Graphics gfx = paintEvnt.Graphics;
            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);

                for (i = 40; i < 640; i = i + 100)
                {
                    gfx.DrawLine(myPen, i, 25, i, 35); 
                }

                for (i = 40; i < 640; i = i + 100)
                {
                    gfx.DrawLine(myPen, i, 55, i, 65);
                }

                Color brushColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255);
                SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(brushColor);

                    int randomnumber = random.Next(0, 601);
                    gfx.FillRectangle(myBrush, 33, 33, randomnumber, 25);

                    if (randomnumber + 33 > max)
                    {
                        max = randomnumber + 33;
                        gfx.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), max, 30, max, 60);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gfx.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), max, 30, max, 60);
                    }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what it looks like: http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/5646/graphmj.jpg
Each time I press the button, new random data is generated and overrides the old graph. However, theres still a problem.
The red indicator is supposed to increase only when the max value has been exceeded and thats what I tried to implement with the if-query in the OnPaint method, yet it will still make up random values sometimes and go totally off, exceeding the old value eventhough the new random value is even lower.. that doesnt make sense.

Heres the project incase anyone wants to try out and help me:
http://up.k10x.net/ambglolrngulg/LevelMeter.zip

I'm really clueless because the code looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use mschart for that. I'd write a control to do the bar and max indicator and then use that on another usercontrol to get the labels and stuff.
Last I looked there's no shape control in .net, so this might give you a few clues.
[open source .net shape control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DotNetShapeControl.aspx)

Comment: ok actually, I decided to go the painting route, its very simple. I draw the borders using drawline and the actual bar (blue in the picture) using drawRectangle. Now the problem is, once I get a new value, I'll have to deleted the old rectangle and draw the new one but I am not sure how to delete an already existing Rectangle.

Comment: just draw the rectangle at it's current size in the background colour, you can skip that step if the value is increasing as well, unless you want to get clever and use a gradient fill or chabge colour as it gets closer to max etc.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy : http://www.dotnetlines.com/Blogs/tabid/85/EntryId/44/Create-a-simple-Column-Chart-Bar-Chart-in-ASP-NET-using-C.aspx

Add the following httphandler in web.config

```
<httpHandlers>

  <add path="ChartImg.axd"

       verb="GET,HEAD,POST"

       type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler,

       System.Web.DataVisualization,

       Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

       PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

       validate="false"/>

</httpHandlers>
```

Page design

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"

CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

 <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"

Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization,

        Version=4.0.0.0,

        Culture=neutral,

        PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>

 //Place the chart control on the page as follows.

    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="600px">

        <Titles>

            <asp:Title ShadowOffset="3" Name="Student Marks" />

        </Titles>

        <Legends>

            <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Legend"

                LegendStyle="Row" />

        </Legends>

        <Series>

            <asp:Series Name="Legend" />

        </Series>

        <ChartAreas>

            <asp:ChartArea Name="studentChartArea" BorderWidth="0" />

        </ChartAreas>

    </asp:Chart>
```

Write the following code in CodeBehind for filling the chart in the Chart control

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    string[] xAxis = { "Student1", "Student2", "Student3", "Student4", "Student5", "Student6" };

    double[] yAxis = { 39, 67, 96, 86, 47, 98 };

    Chart1.Series["Legend"].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis, yAxis);



    Chart1.Series["Legend"].Points[0].Color = Color.Black;

    Chart1.Series["Legend"].Points[1].Color = Color.Bisque;

    Chart1.Series["Legend"].Points[2].Color = Color.Blue;

    Chart1.Series["Legend"].Points[3].Color = Color.BlueViolet;

    Chart1.Series["Legend"].Points[4].Color = Color.Brown;

    Chart1.Series["Legend"].Points[5].Color = Color.CornflowerBlue;



    Chart1.Series["Legend"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;     



    Chart1.ChartAreas["studentChartArea"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;       

}
```

- See more at: http://www.dotnetlines.com/Blogs/tabid/85/EntryId/44/Create-a-simple-Column-Chart-Bar-Chart-in-ASP-NET-using-C.aspx